# Infinite heat capacity or susceptibility means fluctuation on all scales

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I remember reading in an introductory text to phase transition (sorry I don't remember the name) that at a second order phase transition the specific heat and the magnetic susceptibility become infinite and that this implies fluctuations on all length scales.

I understand how this implies strong fluctuations as they are respectively linked to the variance of the energy and of the magnetization, or that being infinite it's not possible to construct a preferred length scale with them; but I'm not sure to understand why it forces the fluctuation to happen at ALL the scales.

Do you have an intuitive argument or example for that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "critical opalescence."  Hard by the transition the fluctuation scale can be centimeters.  That's fairly infinite compared to a wavelength of light where it first becomes visible.